# can you use a constructor's method when defining a method in a seperate constructor

Tags: javascript, methods, constructor

can I do this? If not why? What is a better solution?

```
function ConstructorA(){
  this.ten = function(){
    return 5+5;
  }
}

function ConstructorB(){
  this.fifteen = function(){
     var ten = ConstructorA.ten();
     return 5 + ten;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? To call `ten` you'll need to construct via `ConstructorA`: `var ten = new ConstructorA().ten()`.

Comment: You might be looking for [mix-ins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Mix-ins)

Comment: Your description is vague. It doesn't explain what you're ultimately trying to do. Best I can tell is that you want something like a `static` method. If so, then move the `ten` outside the constructor, and put it directly on the function. `ConstructorA.ten = function() { return 5 + 5 }`. If you use `class` syntax, there's a `static` keyword that provides a shorthand for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call constructors with **`new`**`Constructor`**`()`** like that:

```js
function ConstructorA(){
  this.ten = function(){
    return 5+5;
  }
}

function ConstructorB(){
  this.fifteen = function(){
     var ten = new ConstructorA().ten();
     return 5 + ten;
  }
}

console.log(new ConstructorB().fifteen());
```